# if-else statement do not run

Tags: php, forms, validation, if-statement

I hope you could help me with my problem. My script for validating form (checks if the text-box is not empty and if is it a number; note: in my region we use in decimal number comma not point, PHP works only with decimal point) do not work properly. HTML:

```
...
<form action="http://localhost/kalkulacka.php" method="post" name="formular">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1 dávka(g):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="davka" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bielkoviny v 1 dávke(g):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="bielkoviny" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sacharidy v 1 dávke(g):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sacharidy" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Balenie(g):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="balenie" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
    <tr>
      <td>Cena za balenie(€):</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cena" maxlength="7" size="7"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Vypočítaj"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php

$davka=$_POST['davka'];
$bielkoviny=$_POST['bielkoviny'];
$sacharidy=$_POST['sacharidy'];
$balenie=$_POST['balenie'];
$cena=$_POST['cena'];
$is_valid=true;

function vypocitaj($serving, $proteins, $pack, $price)
{
    $proteins_percentage=($proteins/$serving)*100;
    $price_per_gram=$price/($pack/100*$proteins_percentage);
    printf("1 gram bielkoviny stoji: %.3f", $price_per_gram);
}

if (empty($davka)||empty($bielkoviny)||empty($sacharidy)||empty($balenie)||empty($cena))
{
    echo "Some boxes are empty!";
    $is_valid=false;
}
else /*when I remove this whole "else" block, script at least verifies if are boxes empty by if statement above, but when I add this block, it not even verifies if are boxes empty*/
{
    if (!is_numeric($davka))
    {
        $davka=str_replace(",", ".", $davka);
        if (!is_numeric($davka)
        {
            $is_valid=false;
        }
    }
    if ($is_valid==true && !is_numeric($bielkoviny))
    {
        $bielkoviny=str_replace(",", ".", $bielkoviny);
        if (!is_numeric($bielkoviny)
        {
            $is_valid=false;
        }
    }
    if ($is_valid==true && !is_numeric($sacharidy))
    { 
        $sacharidy=str_replace(",", ".", $sacharidy);
        if (!is_numeric($sacharidy)
        {
            $is_valid=false;
        }
    }
    if ($is_valid==true && !is_numeric($balenie))
    {
        $balenie=str_replace(",", ".", $balenie);
        if (!is_numeric($balenie)
        {
            $is_valid=false;
        }
    }
    if ($is_valid==true && !is_numeric($cena))
    {
        $cena=str_replace(",", ".", $cena);
        if (!is_numeric($cena)
        {
            $is_valid=false;
        }
    }
    if ($is_valid)
    {
        vypocitaj($davka, $bielkoviny, $balenie, $cena);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only number are accepted!";
    }
}
?>
```

The same script written in JavaScript's syntax works properly in JavaScript, but in PHP won't work. When I removed the main "else" statement the main "if" statement worked, but when I added it, the whole code did not work. When I tried each function separately - they worked.

I'm stuck for several days in this and I can't move. I would like to know the reason why it is not work properly. I appreciate any advice. Thanks ;)
Sorry for my English.

Comment: You are using if else more than once. Can you add comments to your code to make clear which if else statement you mean?

Comment: In what way doesn't work? Are variables not the expected value? Are there errors? Have you tried simplifying your code? For example, in your 'main else' block, replace all the code with a simple `echo "ELSE reached"` to see if that bit of the code is being reached (i.e. your if conditional is working the way you expect).

Comment: I suggest you replace the `empty()` function with `isset()`

Comment: thanks for your advice, yes I tried to put echo into each if statement, but never is reached. The result is blank site. When I remove  main "else" statement then "if" statement work.

Comment: Are you from Czech Republic :-)?

Comment: Slovensko :D sakra, len mi nepripominaj hokej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pasted that code to my IDE it told me that there is a missing closing brace:

```
if (!is_numeric($davka))
{
    $davka=str_replace(",", ".", $davka);
    if (!is_numeric($davka)
                        // ^ missing brace here
    {
        $is_valid=false;
    }
}
```

…it should be:

```
if (!is_numeric($davka))
{
    $davka=str_replace(",", ".", $davka);
    if (!is_numeric($davka))
    {
        $is_valid=false;
    }
}
```

If that solves the problem, please use an editor with syntax highlighting…

Comment: thanks a lot ;) finally I can sleep in peacefully. Two days i search a keying mistake. I feel so stupid

Comment: @user3320983 Well, the next thing you should do is install [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or some other IDE or editor that will find those mistakes for you immediately.

Comment: I will do it. Time is so expensive for that mistakes